# Rails 4 CoffeeScript not executing when precompiled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 4 application with some Coffeescript that is mostly used to update lists upon selection of an item in another list - pretty basic stuff.

The script works perfectly in development.  However, as soon as it is precompiled, even though I see the actual code in the precompiled asset file, it will not run at all.

I reduced the code to a very minimal scope, so all it does is display an alert if a combo box is changed and still not working.  I also removed all .coffee files from the assets/javascript directory to only leave this one Coffeescript file and the application.js file to ensure there are no conflicts with other .coffee files.

I also had suspicion about turbolinks, which I then removed and still no change.

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

attendance.coffee

```
  $('#season_id').on "change", ->
     alert('Success!')
```

The form from app/views/attendances/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/attendances/get_attendance_sheet" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />       <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Saison:</td>
                <td><select name="season_id" id="season_id" class="form-control"><option value="">Choisir une saison</option><option value="1">Gadbois 2015</option></select></td>
                <td>Entraînement du:</td>
                <td><select name="session_id" id="session_id" class="form-control"><option value="">Choisir une date d&#39;entraînement</option><option value=""></option></select></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Ouvrir" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form></div>
```

Comment: Poor turbolinks… everybody assumes it's the culprit.

Comment: Could you try `$(document).on 'change', '#season_id', -> alert 'Success'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem, many thanks to @itsnikolay.  The problem was due to the fact that another javascript file was throwing an exception.  By having them all compiled into one single file, the exception would make the whole script stop running, thus not executing the Coffescripts.

In this particular case, it was due to the gem rails-assets-tether that was missing to provide tooltips from the bootstrap library.

When in debug mode, since, all javascript files are loaded independently, exceptions from one file doesn't affect loading the other ones.

Comment: Thank you! Completely glossed over this fact. "When in development environment, since all javascript files are loaded independently, exceptions from one file doesn't affect loading the other ones." The tether exception was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Check you compiled javascript file (http://yousite.net/application-[DIGEST].js . Is there `season_id`? If `season_id` present, then try to change your code on:

```
$ ->
  $('#season_id').on "change", ->
     alert('Success!')
```

Comment: I changed as suggested and got this compiled code:
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('#season_id').on("change", function() {
      return alert('Success!');
    });
  });

}).call(this);

Still nothing happening.

Comment: @Pascal because you have two `season_id` on the page, leave just one

Comment: @Pascal and if it won't work, try change the line on following one: `$('#season_id').first().on 'change', ->`

Comment: I only see one season_id. The other one is session_id.  Unless you reffer to the id and name tags, which should not interfere with each other to my knowledge.

Comment: try to execute in your Chrome console `$('#season_id')`, and paste its result  in comment

Comment: <select name="season_id" id="season_id" class="form-control"><option value="">Choisir une saison</option><option value="1">Gadbois 2015</option></select>

Comment: If I change the application configuration to config.assets.debug=true and serve all scripts individually, everything works fine.  It only stops working when the Coffeescripts are precompiled in the assets pipeline for some reason

Comment: @Pascal need to take close, if can share your screen by Skype, you can add me `inikolay51`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't connect to Skype at the moment, but I can do that a bit later if you are still available.  I can also provide you a login to the staging application if you wish to see the actual output

Comment: If you see that javascript compiled, both Sprockets and CoffeeScript are doing there job. There JS shouldn't be different because of `config.assets.debug = true`, can you compare both and tell us the difference? When it works and when it doesn't.